# Argo workflow template execution failing when I use when condition with withParam loop along with the artifact input

Tags: conditional-operator, argo-workflows, argocd

I've the following workflow template which has when condition `when: "'{{item}}' =~ '^tests/'"`, artifacts input as file path in AWS `S3` bucket and `withParam` loop.

Here is my workflow template

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: process-wft
spec:
  entrypoint: main
  templates:
    - name: main
      inputs:
        parameters:
          - name: dir-process
            default: true
          - name: dir


        artifacts:
          - name: Code

      dag:
        tasks:
          - name: process-wft-tests
            when: "'{{item}}' =~ '^tests/'"
            templateRef:
              name: tf-wf-rn
              template: main
            arguments:
              parameters:
                - name: dir-process
                  value: "{{inputs.parameters.dir-process}}"
              artifacts:
                - name: Code
                  from: "{{inputs.artifacts.Code}}"
            withParam: "{{inputs.parameters.dir}}"
```

here is my input artifact `Code` extracted result which is being passed from my workflow

```
inputs:
  artifacts:
  - archive:
      tar:
        compressionLevel: 9
    archiveLogs: true
    globalName: GitSource
    name: Code
    path: /mnt/out/code
    s3:
      key: process-kfxqf/process-kfxqf-1938174407/GitSource.tgz
```

It is giving the below Error when I run my workflow

```
message: failed to resolve {{inputs.artifacts.Code}}
```

What's the mistake am doing here? if it doesn't work what's the alternate way to get this worked?

**Note: I tried workflow execution by removing when condition, it is working fine. It is giving issue only when I add when condition.**

Comment: Can you share how you're invoking this WorkflowTemplate? Is it with `argo submit --from workflowtemplate/process-wft` or maybe another Workflow with a `workflowTemplateRef`? 

And can you clarify where the second block of code is coming from?

Comment: @Michael Crenshaw - I am invoking this Workflow template with `workflowTemplateRef` from another workflow and the second block of code is the outcome of artifact `Code` mentioned in the workflow template. Second block of code , I just added for better understanding of the outcome of the artifact `Code`.

Comment: This looks very very much like a bug. I'm going to submit an issue and then link here.

Comment: Ok, do we have any workaround to fix this issue in my current workflow template?

Comment: Updated the answer with a potential workaround. Another idea: is there any way you could pass just information _about_ the artifact as parameters and then actually _load_ the artifact in the `main` template of the `tf-wf-rn` WorkflowTemplate?

Comment: Thanks for adding workarounds. I can't pass value of artifact as parameter directly as it is being constructed dynamically

Comment: Yeah, that's what I worried.... even though it's being constructed dynamically, it should theoretically be possible to calculate the S3 key? But maybe not, you know this code better than I do.  :-)

Comment: It might be possible to construct it, but currently we have 100+ workflows and the same artifact being referenced everywhere. If i change in any workflow it'll break everything. Initially I need to think about if it is possible to construct dynamically

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/issues/7385).

It seems that when the condition evaluates to `false`, some code skips populating the artifact (makes sense, save some time), but some other code doesn't respect the `when` condition and still expects the artifact to be populated.

Potential workarounds:

1. Move the conditional logic into the container.

   1. remove the `when` condition
   2. pass the `dir` parameter to the `main` template in your `tf-wf-rn` WorkflowTemplate
   3. change the `main` template to run the regex against the `dir` parameter - if it doesn't match, just exit 0

   This could make the workflow *much* slower, because you'll have to spin up a pod for each iteration of the loop to determine if there's actually any work to be done.
2. If you can calculate all the information *about* the artifact, pass that information as parameters to the `main` template in your `tf-wf-rn` WorkflowTemplate. Then actually *load* the artifact in that non-conditioned, non-looped template. (Basically hopscotch over the problematic code.)
3. Try an older version.

   If you find a working older version, please 1) comment on the bug report and 2) make sure the older version doesn't have any relevant security vulnerabilities before running it on a production system.